# Cordova app build error

Tags: cordova, monaca

When I build cordova app as a android app, following error was occured.

```
$ /data/build-server/cordova/6.5.0/bin/cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-firebase" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-firebase" for android
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase':CordovaError: Uh oh!

- postBuild -
Remove working directories...
Build Error: Error: Sandbox Exec Error: [ Error: Uh oh!
 "/private/tmp/monaca/59d5fa64ff2af27604433921/project/platforms/android/res/values/colors.xml" already exists!]
```

I have no idea hohw can I fix it. Please give me an advice.

Comment: are you runing the commands from inside a cordova project? (/data/build-server/cordova/6.5.0/bin/cordova seems suspicious) have you installed cordova with the -g option (`npm install -g cordova`) you should not have to provide the path to cordova when calling it.

Comment: Thank you for a reply. I don't use cordova command. I use Monaca in order to make a cordova app. Monaca is a total environment web system to make cordova app.